# How to fix "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in the rfind(os.sep.path) + 1:"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, type-conversion, typeerror

I am trying to classify my input image using pre-trained labels and matching that with the label inserted into the input image file name like : "my_name.png" ; which is also there in the label.pickle "my_name"

````
def onClassify(self):
   IMAGE_DIMS = (96, 96, 3)

    image = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Jimit Vaghela/PycharmProjects/Image Classification/gui /cap_images/fold_1/jimit_Image_202084T132225.png")
    output = image.copy()


    # pre-process the image for classification
    image = cv2.resize(image, (IMAGE_DIMS[1], IMAGE_DIMS[0]))
    image = image.astype("float") / 255.0

    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)



    # load the trained convolutional neural network and the label
    # binarizer
    print("[INFO] loading network...")
    model = load_model("C:/Users/Jimit Vaghela/PycharmProjects/Image Classification/gui/classifier/")
    lb = pickle.loads(open("C:/Users/Jimit Vaghela/PycharmProjects/Image Classification/gui/labelbin.pickle", "rb").read())

    # classify the input image
    print("[INFO] classifying image...")
    proba = model.predict(image)[0]
    idx = np.argmax(proba)
    label = lb.classes_[idx]

    # we'll mark our prediction as "correct" of the input image filename
    # contains the predicted label text (obviously this makes the
    # assumption that you have named your testing image files this way)

    filename = "jimit_Image_202084T132225.png".rfind(os.path.sep)[+1:]
    correct = "correct" if filename.rfind(label) != -1 else "incorrect"
    # build the label and draw the label on the image
    label = "{}: {:.2f}% ({})".format(label, proba[idx] * 100, correct)
    output = imutils.resize(output, width=400)
    cv2.putText(output, label, (10, 25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # show the output image
    print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
    self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(output)) ```
````

**The error is in this line:    *filename = "jimit_Image_202084T132225.png".rfind(os.path.sep)[+1:]***

What am I doing wrong here? What should I add in front of .rfind() method.

Desired output as asked by @MisterMiyagi: [image: charmander_counter.png]

> As you can see the input image was named as "charmander_counter.png" in the directory "/examples/charmander_counter.png" and I am using my "my_name.png" replacing the original code.
> To clarify, I have already trained the model with various images of mine in a class named as "my_name"

Comment: ``str.rfind`` returns an *index*, at which the substring was found. Did you mean to ``str.rsplit`` instead? Note that ``os.path.sep`` is the path separator, e.g. ``/`` in ``/usr/bin`` – which is notably absent from ``"jimit_Image_202084T132225.png"``. Since you are applying ``rfind`` to a literal, why not directly write the expected result there? For that matter, what is the expected result?

Comment: `str.rfind` returns an index (integer). Integers don't support indexing or slicing notation.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, Actually I have modified a code which was originally taking arguments from the command like `filename = args["image"][args["image"].rfind(os.path.sep) + 1:]` The arguments were for the input image as `--image examples/charmander_counter.png`. But instead of taking the argument, I am passing the path to the file name simila to the `--image examples/charmander_counter.png`. Is it not going to work like that? Pardon my level of python, I am new to this.

Comment: Do you realise that ``smt[smt.rfind(...) + 1:]`` is *very* different from ``smt.rfind(...)[+1:]``? Either way, the code you have shown does not pass in any arguments, it just works on a statically defined string – you can just write there the *result*, e.g. ``"jimit_Image_202084T132225.png"`` or ``"jimit_Image_202084T132225"``. Note that *you* must know what result is desired, we cannot guess this for you.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The desired result is the input image file that will be classified by the NN on the bases of the labels trained in the network model and then printing it on the output image as you can see from the code snippet.

Comment: I meant what is the *concrete* desired output? Given the "input" ``"jimit_Image_202084T132225.png"``, is the desired output ``"jimit_Image_202084T132225"``, ``"png"``, ``"jimit_Image_202084T132225.png"``, ``"jimit_Image"`` or something else?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Added the desired output from the original image. I am trying to replicate that on my own custom dataset.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, The desired output will be "jimit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to get the file name without the extension then try this

```py
filename = "jimit_Image_202084T132225.png".rsplit(".")[-2]
```

which would give you

> jimit_Image_202084T132225

assuming you only have file names, if the `filenname` might also include path, something like this would work.

```py
filepath = "path/to/file/jimit_Image_202084T132225.png"
filename_with_extension = filepath..rsplit(os.path.sep)[-1] # this will extract the filename, giving you jimit_Image_202084T132225.png
filename = filename_with_extension.rsplit(".")[-2] # this will remove the extension giving you jimit_Image_202084T132225.
```

or in one line

```py
filename = "path/to/file/jimit_Image_202084T132225.png".rsplit(os.path.sep)[-1].rsplit(".")[-2]
```

note that this relies on the file having an extension so if your original file was `jimit_Image_202084T132225` (no .png) then it won't work.
this would also work if you had multiple file extensions like `jimit_Image_202084T132225.new.png` you'd get `jimit_Image_202084T132225.new`, if that is not desired then comment and I'll change it to the desired one

Edit: as mentioned by @MisterMiyagi `os.path` contains tools for doing this, so you can use this to achieve the same thing

```py
os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("path/to/file/jimit_Image_202084T132225.new.png"))[0]
```

Comment: Both ``os.path`` and ``pathlib`` already provide safe, well-defined means to extract/drop extensions and sub-paths. There is no need to manually do this.

Comment: @Jimmar The file is `.png` and is being used as an input image for the classifier network to predict the output of the same image as either correct or incorrect with the percentage from the line `correct = "correct" if filename.rfind(label) != -1 else "incorrect"
    # build the label and draw the label on the image
    label = "{}: {:.2f}% ({})".format(label, proba[idx] * 100, correct)`

Comment: @Jimmar I tried `filename = "path/to/file/jimit_Image_202084T132225.png".rsplit(os.path.sep)[-1].rsplit(".")[-2]` and it fixed the issue, although it does not completely gives me the desired output that I have posted.

Comment: @JimitVaghela what is your desired output for the filename ? wasn't it to get the filename without the extension ? if you are facing issues other than the one stated then I suggest you pick an answer and open another question for the other issue

Comment: @Jimmar I have opened another question in my profile, provided every necessary detail with the expected output I need written there. Care to take a look? Thanks in advance.